# Let Lua overwrite global variables

Tags: lua

I'm using Lua as the configuring language. As everybody knows, configuration should have system-wide one and user's one.

I just found that Lua would keep the original values rather than overwrite them.

For example,this is the first source file,

```
-- a.lua
var=1
```

and the second source file

```
-- b.lua
var=2
```

here's the result:

```
> lua-5.1 
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> dofile ("a.lua")
> dofile ("b.lua")
> print(var)
1
```

Yep. `var` has not been overwritten. This would make user's own configuration not work. Anybody knows how to let Lua overview variables which have the same variable name by default? Thanks very much. (source above is just for example, actually I'm using Lua with C)

**PS:** I checked the test above again and it works.  Please see comments under the answer of Nicol.

Comment: Neither `a.lua` nor `b.lua` writes to the value `a`. Indeed, I have no idea why it doesn't print `nil` or where `1` is coming from. Can you provide a reproducible case for this?

Comment: @NicolBolas sorry I made a mistake. It should be `print (var)` there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual approach is to have a `table` of system parameters, and a `table` of user parameters. E.g.,

a.lua

```
sys = { var = 1; a = 3 }
```

b.lua

```
usr = { a = 5; b = 7 }
```

The config manager does

```
setmetatable(usr,{__index = sys})
```

Test:

```
> =usr.a
5
> =usr.var
1
> =usr.b
7
>
```

Comment: A table is difficult to handle by the manager... Is there a way not to use tables?

Comment: @ekd123: Global variables are *in a table*. The *only* difference between getting a global field and a field from a table is calling `lua_getglobal` vs. `lua_getfield`.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to reproduce your error, but it worked exactly as you expected it would. So if you're getting this, it is almost certainly something you're doing somewhere that you're not mentioning. Are you sure those files contain what you say they do?

Comment: ... Hmmm, I checked again and it works. But my software really doesn't work correctly.. One thing I haven't mentioned: They aren't in the same directory. Strange enough, if I copy the system-wide one (which I do not have the permission to write) into the same directory as the user's conf, it'll work. Maybe a bug?

Comment: @ekd123 Can you reproduce the problem in a Lua shell? If not, then yes, there is probably a bug, but it's likely somewhere in your code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: @ekd123 I don't see any small test above…? Lua itself completely doesn't care where code comes from, it's unlikely to be the problem.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek I just found that I used "~" inside the test, so Lua failed because of this. My program uses [this GObject class](https://github.com/ekd123/hshell/blob/master/src/hs-ext.c), just used hs_ext_global_get_str().

Comment: @ekd123: At this point, it's becoming impossible to understand what the actual problem you're having is *now*. You need to ask a *new* question based on your current problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes the same problem. It returns the value of system conf rather than user conf. Changing the system conf is OK.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, sorry, I see now.